# Vertical nested scrollviews. Prevent child to call parent's refresh control

Tags: android, react-native

I have two scrollviews, the parent is a scrollview with a refresh control element on it. Then there are a few childs including a flatlist with a fixed height. The problem is that if the user trys to scroll up the flatlist the parent scrollview tries to call the refresh control, this doesnt happen on ios.

On iOS the parent refresh control is only called if i'm trying to scroll anywhere outside of the flatlist.

Comment: To see a reproducible code check this expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/@moyolvera/thankful-toffee

Comment: Yeah mee too. Im thinking call back refreshcontroll on the paretn

Comment: hello, I have this problem too.
can you fix this?

Comment: anyone managed to solve this ? 